# Wordpress site can not send or receive Email

Tags: wordpress, email

we are using WP Mail SMTP Plugin by Mail Bank

Checking your settings
Sending Test Email to example@gmail.com
Email Status : Email Not Sent

---

Debug Output :

---

220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP m68sm9257127qkc.5 - gsmtp
EHLO localhost
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2607:f298:5:103f::578:ccb5]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
AUTH PLAIN
334
AHBpeHN0ZXJzdHVkaW9AZ21haWwuY29tAFBpeHN0dWRpbzgyODY=
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials m68sm9257127qkc.5 - gsmtp

Your Web Host provider may have installed a firewall between you and the server.
Contact the admin of the server and ask if they allow outgoing communication on port 25,465,587.
It seems like they are blocking certain traffic. Ask them to open the ports.

Comment: In your answer, please explain what is the issue and what you actually want. If this is an error when does it occur?

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that the credentials are right ( because I see the **Username and Password not accepted** message ) then write to your hosting administrator to open the mailing ports `25,465,587`

Comment: Thank u..!! @Anatolii Bivol

Comment: @vpatel You are welcome. Also you could accept the answer ;)